# iPad+Set imagepickers quality to low

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

In my iPad App I allow the user to take multiple photos and then zip all the images and upload it to server. The problem i am facing is due to large size images,the size of the zip file is increasing and it fails while uploading. How can i save low quality images immediately after image is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image is captured in png format.Convert it to JPG format.This will help reduce size of image to some extent.

or else compress image by some factor

here is the code

//code

```
if(imagesize>[MAX_SIZE_IMAGE intValue]){

   while (imagesize>[MAX_SIZE_IMAGE intValue]){

        NSData *data=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(Image, 0.1f);

        imagesize=[data length];
    }
}

jpgImage =[UIImage imageWithData:data];

return jpgImage;
```

here set MAX_SIZE_IMage to some value and then compress image by factor of 0.1 till it reduces to size less than max image size

Answer (score 0):

FUnction to resize image:

```
  -(UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image width:(float)imgwidth height:(float)imgheight
  {
   CGSize imgSize; 
   imgSize.width= imgwidth;
   imgSize.height= imgheight;
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imgSize);
   [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,imgSize.width,imgSize.height)];
   UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   return newImage;
  }
```

You can store all images picked in array. Now before creating zip resize image to your size:

```
  for(int i = 0; [array count]; i++)
  {
    // call resize function here
    //Again store all resized image in another array Now u have all images in low quality for zip
  }
```